# How often does Apple.com update their refurbished stock?

Tags: hardware, apple-store

How often does Apple.com update their [refurbished stock](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals)? Is there a schedule, is it based upon product availability, or a combination of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's no schedule, it is all based upon product availability.As soon as the product has passed all the Refurbishing steps, it's posted. What's certain is that products don't last long, so keen buyers are suggested to check every day, or even every hour.